# why extracted feature have a lot of zero i keras vgg16?

Tags: keras

this is my code i get rid of the last dense layers and predict the features .

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, BatchNormalization
import os, shutil
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import keras 

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet', 
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))

train_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/small_data/data/train"
valid_dir = "/content/drive/My Drive/small_data/data/validation"

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./155)
batch_size = 1

img_width, img_height = 224, 224 

def extract_features(directory, sample_count):
    features = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count, 7, 7, 512))  # Must be equal to the output of the convolutional base
    labels = np.zeros(shape=(sample_count,6))
    # Preprocess data
    generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(directory,
                                            target_size=(img_width,img_height),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode='binary')
    # Pass data through convolutional base
    i = 0
    for inputs_batch, labels_batch in generator:
        features_batch = conv_base.predict(inputs_batch)
        features[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = features_batch
        labels[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size] = labels_batch
        i += 1
        if i * batch_size >= sample_count:
            break
    return features, labels


train_features, train_labels = extract_features(train_dir, 43)
validation_features, validation_labels = extract_features(valid_dir, 28)
```

the value that i get when i print train festures is just a big list with numbers like this 
(0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.08844849, 0.40013123, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.59819716, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.03238258, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.32838312, 0.42723358, 0.10626598, 0.        , 0.1936072 ,
       0.71200961, 0.38265556, 0.06889667, 0.3056691 , 0.35969719,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.9093371 , 0.17480908, 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.07098073, 0.41668156, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.93668669, 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 1.08008015, 0.        , 0.24190509, 1.52572215)
as you can see there is a lot of zero in the features so i want to know why ?

Comment: Because it uses the ReLU activation, which sets any negative value to zero.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro : so what should i do ? change the activation to elu  with the same weights of the vgg16? and i i changed the relu should i change it in all the layers or just the dense layers ? iam new to this field so i need your advice

Comment: Advice on what? I do not see any problem, this is normal.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro i want to use this features to train my LSTM so is this normal to train  it with this number of zero in my features ?